# Dynamic cargo feature flags

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to change the feature flags of an included library at run time? Or more specifically change the feature flags depending on certain cpu feature flags? Can it be done pragmatically or can it be done via cli arguments?

We have this library (curve25519-dalek) that allows you to use default, or AVX2, or IFMA. But only if your cpu running the code can support it. Is there a way to create a binary that will pass the correct feature flag to the library so that your code will run the correct instruction set? You would want to run the fastest instruction set as the speed gains are significant.

Comment: No. Features are a compile time cencept. "allows you to use default, or AVX2, or IFMA" that's not how features are supposed to work. They are supposed to be additive.

Comment: Have you looked at the [multiversion crate](https://crates.io/crates/multiversion)?

Comment: This looks very help full, but that also means modifying the underlaying crate. Something We dont have control over. 
In an ideal world, it needs to be in the bottom crate.